# Convert all dates column to datetime of multiple DataFrames in a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have multiple `DataFrames` stored in a `dictionary` and I try to change the type of the `Dates` column from `object` to `datetime` for all `DataFrames` in the `dictionary` at the same time.

This would be an example with two `DataFrames` `df1` & `df2`.

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Dates':['2021-01-01', '2021-01-03', '2021-01-04', '2021-01-05', '2021-01-06'],
    'ID1':[0,0,0.1,0.2,0.1],
    'ID2':[0,0,0.1,0.2,0.1],
    'ID3':[0.1,0,0,0.2,0.4],
    'ID4':[0,0,0.1,0.2,0.1], 
    'ID6':[0,0,0.1,0.2,0.1]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Dates':['2021-01-01', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-03', '2021-01-04', '2021-01-05'], 
    'ID2':[3,6,3,-1,3],
    'ID4':[1,2.4,-2,1,4],
    'ID5':[4,3,3,-3,4],
    'ID6':[2,1.5,2,-2,3]})

dfs = dict()
dfs['df1'] = df1
dfs['df2'] = df2
```

I try to figure out a way to convert the column; `Dates` to datetime format within the `dictionary` for all `DataFrames` at the same time. So far, I was only able to convert them individually before putting them together into a `dictionary` with: `df1['Dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Dates'])`

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dictionary comprehension with [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
dfs = {k:v.assign(Dates = pd.to_datetime(v['Dates'])) for k, v in dfs.items()}
```

EDIT:

```
dfs = {k:v.assign(Dates = pd.to_datetime(v['Dates'])).sort_values('Dates', ignore_index=True) 
      for k, v in dfs.items()}
```

Comment: Many thanks! Is there also a way to adjust your solution to additionally order by dates?

Comment: @fjurt - Answer was edited.